# Points in a compact subset of $R^k$

Tags: general-topology

**Problem:**
Let $A$ be a compact nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}^k$, and let $\delta = \sup \{d(x, y): x, y \in A\}$, where $d(x, y)$ is the standard metric.

Does $A$ contain the points $x_0, y_0$ such that $d(x_0, y_0) = \delta$?

At a glance it seems so, where $x_0$ and $y_0$ are the "furthest apart points" in $A$. Since A is compact, by Heine-Borel Theorem, these furthest points are in $A$. How do I show this proof formally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the function
\begin{align}
d:A\times A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}
\end{align}
which is continuous since
\begin{align}
|d(x, y)-d(x_0, y_0)| \leq& |d(x, y)-d(x, y_0)| + |d(x, y_0)-d(x_0, y_0)|\\
\leq&\ d(y, y_0) + d(x, x_0).
\end{align}
Since $A\times A$ is compact then, it follows $d$ attains its maximum on $A\times A$.

Moreover, it's clear that the maximum of $d$ on $A\times A$ is $\delta$. Suppose $d(x, y)=\max d(x, y) <\delta$, then there exists $(x', y') \in A\times A$ such that
$d(x', y')>d(x, y)$ which contradicts $(x, y)$ attains the maximum on $A\times A$. Hence $\max d(x, y)\geq \delta$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that $A\times A$ is compact and the function distance is continuous then it attains its maximum at some point $(x_{0},y_{0}) \in A\times A$. It follows that $x_{0},y_{0} \in A$.

Answer (score 0):

1. $d: A \times A \subset \mathbb{R}^{2k} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $(x,y) \mapsto d(x,y)$ is continuous
2. $A \times A$ compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^k \times \mathbb{R}^k$ which by Heine-Borel implies $A \times A$ is closed and bounded
3. By Extreme Value Theorem) $d$ attains its sup, inf on the set $A \times A$.